# Chess engine stock fish process for mobile

Tags: unity, chess

I am making the chess interface I designed for a game. I am using the process to get answers from a stock fish binary:

```
stockfish = new Process {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
                    FileName = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory () + "\\Assets\\Scripts\\Stockfish\\stockfish.exe",
                    Arguments = "",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                }

            };
```

The problem I face is it worked for my Windows build but for mobile package build it won't work with the executable. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to make this work like this. You need to update the package name in the file path.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Assets.Scripts
{
    public class EngineCommunicator
    {
        public static Process mProcess;
        public static string fileName = "stockfish.android.armv7";
        public static void Communicate()
        {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            string filepath = "E:\\Personal\\Unity\\Chess2d\\Assets\\Plugins\\Windows\\stockfish_13_win_x64";
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
            string filepath = "/data/data/com.tiringbring.Chess2d/lib/stockfish.android.armv7.so";
            UI.Instance.AddJob(() =>
            {
                UI.Instance.TestText.GetComponent<TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI>().text = filepath;
            });
            

            if (!File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                UI.Instance.AddJob(() =>
                {
                    UI.Instance.TestText.GetComponent<TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI>().text =UI.Instance.TestText.GetComponent<TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI>().text +" "+ "file not found";
                });
            }else{
                UI.Instance.AddJob(() =>
                {
                    UI.Instance.TestText.GetComponent<TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI>().text =UI.Instance.TestText.GetComponent<TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI>().text +" "+ "file found";
                });
            }
#else
        string filepath = Application.streamingAssetsPath+ "/" + "stockfish_13_x64.exe";
#endif
            // creating the process and communicating with the engine
            mProcess = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = filepath,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true
            };
            mProcess.StartInfo = si;
            mProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(MProcess_OutputDataReceived);
            mProcess.Start();
            mProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
            mProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();

            SendLine("uci");
            SendLine("isready");
            SendLine("ucinewgame");
            SendLine("position startpos");
            SendLine("go infinite searchmoves e2e4 d2d4");


        }


        private static void SendLine(string command)
        {
            mProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);
            mProcess.StandardInput.Flush();
        }

        private static void MProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string text = e.Data;
            UI.Instance.AddJob(() =>
            {
                UI.Instance.TestText.GetComponent<TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI>().text = UI.Instance.TestText.GetComponent<TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI>().text +" "+ text;
            });

            UnityEngine.Debug.Log(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Put the file in Assets/Android directory with .so extension.

[image]

It will be copied automatically in lib folder on android mobile

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This line should only ever work in Windows version (or for versions that your VS supports):

```
FileName = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory () + "\\Assets\\Scripts\\Stockfish\\stockfish.exe",
```

For Unity's builder, you need to use [Application.dataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html) or [Application.persistentDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html). I've had success with using both, the former for accessing the game folder and the latter for saving or loading files.

Comment: You'd also need a version of the external binary compiled for your target platform, as the exe is a Windows executable.

Comment: What is the stranded binary for Android and how can i access it ? Can you guide me through on it.

Comment: @AhmadIftikhar `apk`, which you get by changing the build target in Unity.